# Annotation on a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Is there any chrome extension which has an API available for a web page to pass on an array of text terms which highlights the occurrences of those words in the rendered article ?

eg :

Article : JavaScript (/ˈdʒɑːvəˌskrɪpt/[5]) is a high-level, dynamic, untyped, and interpreted programming language.[6] It has been standardized in the ECMAScript language specification.[7] Alongside HTML and CSS, it is one of the three essential technologies of World Wide Web content production.

Annotations Array : ['programming language', 'HTML', 'CSS']

What I am expecting is to pass this array to a preinstalled API in chrome which in turn highlights the word in the rendered page?

Any help on this direction is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can develop by own

You can use rangy-textrange.js which is javascript library to highlight searching words

here is the demo link url:

http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textrange.html